# Erro ao enviar dados para View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Consulta para trazer os usuários.

```
public IEnumerable PopulaTabelaUsuario()
{
     var banco = new DbBancoContext();
     var listaUsuarios = (from l in banco.USUARIOS_PROCESSO 
         select new{ l.ID_USUARIO, l.NOME_USUARIO }).ToList();
     return  listaUsuarios;
}
```

Minha controller.

```
public ActionResult AreaPrincipal()
{
    var lista = new ConsultasNecessarias();
    var usuarios = lista.PopulaTabelaUsuario();
    //var r = new DbBancoContext();
    //var s = r.USUARIOS_PROCESSO.Select(m=>m.NOME_USUARIO).ToList();
    return View(usuarios);           
}
```

Minha View.

```
@model IEnumerable<ControleVisita.Models.USUARIOS_PROCESSO>    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Área Principal";        
}

@section Menu{        
}
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id Usuário</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @item.ID_USUARIO)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @item.NOME_USUARIO)</td>
            </tr>          
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mas quando executo apresenta o seguinte erro.

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`2[System.Int32,System.String]]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ControleVisita.Models.USUARIOS_PROCESSO]'.

Comment: O problema nem é do bootstrap, é do tipo de dados que estás a enviar para a view

Comment: Concordo CesarMiguel coloquei apenas pois existe o webgrid mas não queria usar. Gostaria de saber como corrijo a questão dos tipos de dados?

Comment: [off-topic] Rabelos, favor não confundir as tags [tag:mvc] com [tag:asp.net-mvc]

Comment: O problema esta no facto de ter declarado na view que ia passar um model do tipo USUARIOS_PROCESSO. O seu controller esta a passar na realidade uma classe anonima que contem os dados que selecionou na query (o tal `new {...}`). Solucao sera ou alterar a query para devolver o tal USUARIOS_PROCESSO ou entao alterar a View com o tipo enviado (como duvido que de para colocar um tipo anonimo, eu criaria uma List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o ***select new***, será criado um novo objeto do tipo anonimo como resultado da consulta.

Você não pode retornar um IEnumerable anonimo (`IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`) porque o tipo a ser retornado não é conhecido.

Tente modificar seu método *PopulaTabelaUsuario()* de consulta para retornar `IEnumerable<USUARIOS_PROCESSO>`.

```
public IEnumerable<USUARIOS_PROCESSO> PopulaTabelaUsuario()
{
    var banco = new DbBancoContext();
    IEnumerable<USUARIOS_PROCESSO> listaUsuarios = (
        from l in banco.USUARIOS_PROCESSO
        select new USUARIOS_PROCESSO { l.ID_USUARIO, l.NOME_USUARIO }
    ).ToList();
    return  listaUsuarios;        
}
```